# Enroll Spring REST/SOAP service to XA transaction

Tags: spring, xa

I have in mind an scenario that theoretically looks possible to me, but I cannot find any information on the web.

The technological environment is Java with Spring, but I am open to other alternatives.

I have a service (ServiceA) that wraps a DB transaction using @Transactional. As part of the logic, it needs to call a remote service (for the sake of example, let us suppose REST, but SOAP or others may also apply). Such service (ServiceB) is also transactional using @Transactional itself.

Obviously, there may be a consistence problem: for example, ServiceB may COMMIT and ServiceA may fail after the remote call, hence ROLLBACK... but ServiceB is not ROLLBACK'd. Obviously.

XA to the rescue. In theory. ServiceA can start an XA distributed transaction, ServiceB enrolls in the same XA distributed transaction and when ServiceA ends, it can do a two-phase commit to both ServiceB (and its DB) and to its own DB.

But... I have not been able to found an example of this setup. Every example of distributed XA transactions that I can find uses two DBs (usualy an SQL JDBC database plus a JMS) used from the same service.

Do I have any theoretical missconception that renders this scenario undoable? Or just I am making a mistake searching Google? Any example of something like this?

Thanks.

PS: I know about others solutions, such as eventual consistency, but that is not what I am asking about.

Comment: I'm doing a XA-POC for one enterprise scenario, issue looks similar:   (1) Springboot integration app  that exposes rest-api and soap-ws- uses camel for some orchestration (2) Must be deployable in Websphere8.5.5.12 (3) 3 GUI clients use the exposed rest/soap api as single integration point. (4) Integration-app integrates downstream to 1 db , 1 ejb-soap-ws , 1 soap-ws-cobol (5)  Xa commit guarantee a must.  Will see how this goes. I'm thinking of using jboss-Narayana-XA, I hope it works with soap services, and does not conflict with Websphere-8.5.5.12 during deployment. Will keep posted.